# Filter JSON with unique key/values

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object structured as such:

```
var theSchools = {
  Bradley University: "bru", 
  Knox College: "knox", 
  Southern Illinois University Edwardsville: "siue",…
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is a way of retrieving the key, in this case the school name, by supplying the value, the schools 'code.'

It does not appear that I will be able to have this restructured correctly, i.e.

```
var theSchools = [
  {
    schoolName:"Bradley University",
    schoolCode: "bru"    
  }
  {
    schoolName: "Knox College",
    schoolCode: "knox"
  }
]
```

so I'm kind of stuck with what I got.

I know the following code is incorrect, but it's essentially what I want to achieve:

```
if(getParameterByName("schoolId").length>0){
    var schoolid = getParameterByName("schoolId");
    var schoolName= theSchools.schoolid;        

    jQuery("h1").after("<h2>Welcome to <strong>"+schoolName+"</strong></h2>")
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) to loop over each property in the object, and return the property name if the value matches:

```js
var theSchools = {
  "Bradley University": "bru", 
  "Knox College": "knox", 
  "Southern Illinois University Edwardsville": "siue"
};

function findSchool(code) {
    for (var s in theSchools) {
        if (theSchools[s] === code)
            return s;
    }
    return null;
}

document.getElementById('school').innerText = findSchool('knox');
```

```html
<div id="school"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is if you really need it this way (see answer @James), here's what you requested:

```
var theSchools = {
  "Bradley University": "bru", 
  "Knox College": "knox", 
  "Southern Illinois University Edwardsville": "siue"
}, schoolMap = {};

for (var schoolName in theSchools) {
  var code = theSchools[ schoolName ];
  schoolMap[ code ] = schoolName;
}

document.body.innerHTML = schoolMap["bru"]; // Bradley University
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use a for loop to check if property exists. Use `hasOwnProperty` method.

```
if (theSchools.hasOwnProperty("Knox College")) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/7q9czdpc/

Comment: You need to know the name of the property in order to do that.  The OP knows the value of the property (the school code) and needs to find its name.